# Error Working with Type Methods

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

Ok, I've been working out of Apple's Swift manual and came across this example.  I typed it in and received a 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) error on:

```
if level > highestUnlockedLevel { highestUnlockedLevel = level }
```

I went back and checked my work. I compared what I typed to the example in the book via TextWrangler, no differences.  I then rebooted my machine, no luck, then went back to try it on Xcode 6 Beta release 7.  Same error.  In fact the code below was taken from the book.  Can some one please try this and see if they receive the same error?

```
struct LevelTracker {
    static var highestUnlockedLevel = 1
    static func unlockLevel(level: Int) {
        if level > highestUnlockedLevel { highestUnlockedLevel = level }
    }
    static func levelIsUnlocked(level: Int) -> Bool {
        return level <= highestUnlockedLevel
    }
    var currentLevel = 1
    mutating func advanceToLevel(level: Int) -> Bool {
        if LevelTracker.levelIsUnlocked(level) {
            currentLevel = level
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

class Player {
    var tracker = LevelTracker()
    let playerName: String
    func completedLevel(level: Int) {
        LevelTracker.unlockLevel(level + 1)
        tracker.advanceToLevel(level + 1)
    }
    init(name: String) {
        playerName = name
    }
}

var player = Player(name: "Argyrios")
player.completedLevel(1)
println("highest unlocked level is now \(LevelTracker.highestUnlockedLevel)")
```

Comment: It seems to work fine in an application, but I have the same problem in a playground.  I'd say submit a bug to bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`highestUnlockedLevel` defined as `static` therefore change line

```
highestUnlockedLevel = level
```

to:

```
LevelTracker.highestUnlockedLevel = level
```

---

*Playground*

```
struct LevelTracker {
    static var highestUnlockedLevel = 1

    static func unlockLevel(level: Int) {
        if level > highestUnlockedLevel {
            LevelTracker.highestUnlockedLevel = level
        }
    } 
}    

LevelTracker.unlockLevel(5)
```

Comment: Hmm... this does work around the crash, but the crash itself is still a bug.

Comment: Since the usage is within a static method, there's no effective difference between the two.  It does work around the crash (note it's a runtime error not compile time), but the underlying problem should still be reported to Apple.  Note also that in an application it works fine, there's just some issue with it in the repl.

Comment: Thanks Maxim, fyi I'm not sure if you worked through the book but in the discussion of what is happening you can find this statement,“(Note that these type methods can access the highestUnlockedLevel static property without your needing to write it as LevelTracker.highestUnlockedLevel.)”  I'll submit a bug to Apple.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: Update: I have it on good authority that a future update to Xcode will resolve this issue.